# Angular / Aura / Bootstrap - How to decide?

Tags: salesforce1-platform, aura, angular, angularjs

With the advent of aura framework, I was wondering how to decide if I want to go ahead with aura framework or may be I want to create with tried and tested angular with bootstrap framework for my responsive apps.

What adavantage / disadvantage do we have of one over another? or how to decide if I really need to learn aura?

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [User Interface Development Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev_overview/lex_dev_overview_future) trailhead.

In a nut shell, if you are doing greenfield development go with Lightning Components route along with Lightning Design system (Salesforce's Responsive CSS framework), as its more aligned with Salesforce's long-term UI strategy. Go with Angualar & Bootstrap if you already invested in them and need to deliver solution quickly.